# How can I add a picture within a folder to my github readme?

Tags: github

Within my repository on github I have an assets folder, and within that is my picture which is weatherdashboard1.png . I would like to add this picture to my readme and have tried doing it like this:

```
![Screenshot](assets/weatherdashboard1.png?raw=true "Title")
```

The picture is not showing. All that appears is the text "screenshot". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
![Screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/assets/weatherdashboard1.png)
```

Replace *user* with your username and *repo* with your repo name, replace *master* with your branch name if needed